# Why the clone() method does not work properly?

Tags: java, clone

I have a 2-dimensional vector called 'link_occur_nodup' which contains data as [[5, 2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1]]. Now, if i try to do

```
Vector<Vector<Integer>> temp=(Vector<Vector<Integer>>) link_occur_nodup.clone();
    temp.elementAt(0).set(1, 50);
    System.out.println(temp+" "+link_occur_nodup);
```

The output is:
[[5, 50, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1]] [[5, 50, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1]]
Iam wondering why does the value being changed in both of the vectors?. Instead it has to be only in the 'temp' vector. Can someone explain please?

Comment: You need to override the implementation of clone. By default it shallow copy only.

Answer (score 12):

`clone` only does a shallow copy: so you get a new `Vector` with references to the same objects as the original.  This is the expected behavior.

If you want different behavior, you'll need to manually copy the inner `Vector`s yourself.  (This is one of the many reasons why the use of `clone` is ill-advised.)

Comment: So you mean to say using clone(), both of them shares the same copy , altering one will also alter the other??..Instead you suggest to copy manually??..In that case what is actually the difference between clone() and copy() in java collections??

Comment: @MrSmith42 You should use `[]` to link Javadocs because of the parentheses: [Vector.clone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#clone()). Also, link the Java 6 docs, almost no one uses 1.4.

Comment: @user1876712: Altering the _elements_ of one will also alter the _elements_ of the other.  You can add and remove elements from the copied vector and it won't affect the other; you just can't modify the elements themselves.  In any event, there is no practical difference between `clone` and the copy constructors, and in general you should never use `clone` anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You've cloned the *outer* Vector.

Your cloned vector contains the same inner vectors as the original one.